# Client-Server Android showing NOROUTETOHOST

Tags: android, sockets, networking, tcp, routes

I have a simple Client- Server App with Android devices.
When tried connecting on Server. NOROUTETOHOST received.
[TCP\IP client - EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522396/tcp-ip-client-ehostunreach-no-route-to-host)

In the above discussion , Thought its between PC-ANDROID , I tried everything.

- Firewall off
- Machine IP used correctly - server shows 192.168.0.3
- Port is checked 8080
  When i tried between emulators.It worked with IP 127.0.0.1

Please provide inputs.

GIThub code links

https://github.com/navaljoshi/ServerNaval2

[https://github.com/navaljoshi/ClientNaval2](https://github.com/navaljoshi/ServerNaval2)

Comment: What is the client's IP-address. What does the client's routing table contain? How is the connection set up, directly or is a switch involved? Can you ping the server from the client?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TCP\IP client - EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522396/tcp-ip-client-ehostunreach-no-route-to-host)

Comment: Client and server are 2 android phones on same wifi.