# java.net.ConnectException on WIFI

Tags: java, android, wifi, connectionexception

I write an app for android OS which uses internet connection.

I installed app on my phone with enabled WiFi and MOBILE connection.

There is a problem: when I come to WiFi network range after MOBILE, my phone correctly enables WiFi and disables MOBILE, but I have an error in my app:

```
E/xxx    (29249): class java.net.ConnectException
E/xxx    (29249): failed to connect to domain.com/x.x.x.x (port 443): isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
E/wpa_supplicant(  766): android_multicast_filter_startstop: failed to issue private commands
E/xxx    (29249): class java.net.ConnectException
E/xxx    (29249): failed to connect to domain.com/x.x.x.x (port 443): isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
```

Other apps are work fine with network. What is wrong?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522396/tcp-ip-client-ehostunreach-no-route-to-host

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Comment: Does your WiFi Router block outgoing traffic on port 443? Does your provider block it?

Comment: Fildor, so I added <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" /> as intent-filter for activity and I think it helped, am I right?