# Connection to IP is refused when trying to connect from android application

Tags: android, httpconnection

I am trying to connect my android app with server which is running in same PC,ip is 192.168.1.129,and tomcat port is 8081,getting below issue,Can any one help me to resolve this?

```
10-07 15:51:45.672 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.129:8081 refused
10-07 15:51:45.673 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:188)
10-07 15:51:45.673 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
10-07 15:51:45.673 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
10-07 15:51:45.673 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:379)
10-07 15:51:45.673 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:580)
10-07 15:51:45.673 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:503)
10-07 15:51:45.674 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:481)
10-07 15:51:45.679 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at com.chronicwatch.app.utils.WebRequest.post(WebRequest.java:72)
10-07 15:51:45.679 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at com.chronicwatch.app.utils.WebRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(WebRequest.java:54)
10-07 15:51:45.679 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at com.octo.android.robospice.request.CachedSpiceRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(CachedSpiceRequest.java:48)
10-07 15:51:45.680 29710-5937/com.net.app  W/System.err:     at com.octo.android.robospice.request.DefaultRequestRunner.processRequest(DefaultRequestRunner.java:150)
10-07 15:51:45.680 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at com.octo.android.robospice.request.DefaultRequestRunner$1.run(DefaultRequestRunner.java:217)
10-07 15:51:45.680 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
10-07 15:51:45.680 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-07 15:51:45.681 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-07 15:51:45.681 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-07 15:51:45.681 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-07 15:51:45.681 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.129 (port 8081) after 15000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
10-07 15:51:45.682 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:238)
10-07 15:51:45.682 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:171)
10-07 15:51:45.683 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
10-07 15:51:45.683 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
10-07 15:51:45.683 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
10-07 15:51:45.683 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
10-07 15:51:45.683 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:124)
10-07 15:51:45.683 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:149)
10-07 15:51:45.685 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     ... 16 more
10-07 15:51:45.685 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
10-07 15:51:45.686 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
10-07 15:51:45.686 29710-5937/com.net.app W/System.err:     ... 23 more
```

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522396/tcp-ip-client-ehostunreach-no-route-to-host

Comment: Please, post some code

Comment: `connect my android app with server which is running in same PC`. Android apps cannot run on PC´s. Do you mean that your app runs in an Android Emulator which is on that same PC?

Comment: @greenapps, App is running in mobile,Server is PC

Comment: Ok. But why not tell if the Android device is on mobile connection or wifi.

Comment: Phone is in wifi,Pc is LAN

Comment: `java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.129 (port 8081) after 15000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)`. You have two types of exception. This is somewhat different from a 'connection refused'. Is the ip ok?

Comment: both PC and phone should have same PUBLIC IP right?,actually i am having two LAN and wifi connection

Answer (score 0):

There can be two problems. First the firewall can prevent access. Switch it off for a test. Second: Maybe Tomcat is bound to localhost/127.0.0.1 only. Have a check in its settings.

Comment: firwall is already disabled,How to check  Tomcat is bound to localhost/127.0.0.1?

Comment: You are the one who installed Tomcat. Settings? I don't know Tomcat. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed,My public IP of my PC is different,Public IP of android phone is different(connected to another wi-fi),But both should be same