# Android ConnectException - No route to host

Tags: android, sockets, connection

So I have an android application that communicate with a server through `Socket`. It was working yesterday at a point. In the evening I wanted to work more on it but it throws a exception without me modifying the code at all.
After remaking the project 2 times I tested the connection with an app that I know that works 100% because I tried it few days ago.

After researching my problem on web I found out that it might be due to a malware software i installed yesterday. I uninstalled it but it still doesn't work.

I ll not post any code here because it isn't relevant. (as i said i tried with something that should work but it doesn't)

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /(my ip is here) (port 2225): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
                                                                    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
                                                                    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
                                                                    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:163)
                                                                    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:592)
                                                                    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226)
                                                                    at com.shoppiness.radu.jshoppiness.Client.run(Client.java:63)
                                                                    at com.shoppiness.radu.jshoppiness.MainActivity$connectTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:77)
                                                                    at com.shoppiness.radu.jshoppiness.MainActivity$connectTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:61)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
                                                                    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
                                                                    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
                                                                    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
                                                                    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
                                                                    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183) 
                                                                    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:163) 
                                                                    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:592) 
                                                                    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226) 
                                                                    at com.shoppiness.radu.jshoppiness.Client.run(Client.java:63) 
                                                                    at com.shoppiness.radu.jshoppiness.MainActivity$connectTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:77) 
                                                                    at com.shoppiness.radu.jshoppiness.MainActivity$connectTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:61) 
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Please refer this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522396/tcp-ip-client-ehostunreach-no-route-to-host

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a lan server make sure both devices (android and server) are on the same wifi.

Your firewall might be blocking the connection to.

Comment: Server is supposed to recieve message from android devices all around the country. I tried to connect it on mobile data then on local wi fi but both do not work.

Answer (score 0):

So if you are hosting the server, make sure you portforwarded the wifi the server is running on. That will allow trafic to go through your router and to server.

Comment: I did it. Few days ago clients could connect at ports I'm trying right now.  It's not about portforwarding.

Comment: Should I try connecting to it?

Comment: You can try. 5.15.78.212 ip, 2223 port.

Comment: I just coded fast a client version for computer. It is located on the server. The thing is that when I try to put "localhost" instead of the actual ip it works. But when I type there my ip it doesn't.

Comment: @Radu ill try it

Comment: Dave server is down right now. But i apreciate you want to help. Thanks.

Comment: @Radu Ok your welcome. Hopefully you can get it to work!

Comment: I hope so. It s my laptop that causes trouble. I tried with a code that is supposed to work but it doesnt. It keeps saying that there is no route to host.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably just because your device is not connectd to the internet. Connect it to wifi and try again. Good luck

Comment: It is connected.