# exposing api via secure gateway

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I want to expose one blue zone api to external customers via secure-gateway, I am using docker as the client, but I always met below errors (the api server is in DST environment), can anyone help me on this? I have added the host name and port into ACL file, also, I tried adding --allow when I run docker, it will disable 'deny all'

> [INFO] (Client ID d83dty5MIJA_rVI) Connection #2 is being established to ralbz001234.cloud.dst.ibm.com:8888
>   [2017-09-06 20:59:19.210] [ERROR] (Client ID d83dty5MIJA_rVI) Connection #1 to destination ralbz001234.cloud.dst.ibm.com:8888 had error: EHOSTUNREACH

When I add secure-gateway, the resource loacated filed, I choose On-Premises, is this correct?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`EHOSTUNREACH` is an issue with the underlying system not being able to find a route to the host you've provided.  From the machine hosting the docker client, are you able to access the resource located at `ralbz001234.cloud.dst.ibm.com:8888`? If the host is able to connect, then you could try adding `--net=host` to the `docker run` command:

```
docker run --net=host -it ibmcom/secure-gateway-client <gatewayID> -t <security_token> --allow
```

If the host is unable to connect as well, then [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12522478/5749279) may shed more light on routing.