# EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host) Error in SSL certificate check

Tags: angular, cordova, ssl, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using the Cordova plugin Cordova-plugin-sslcertificatechecker 5.1.0 to check the SSL certificate, the code is running fine but in some device, it gives me this error

> failed to connect xyx.com/123.455.5678.(port 123) after 15000ms : isconnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (no route to host)

It only gives this error in some devices.
here is the [link to the plugin site and sample code](https://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/ssl-certificate-checker)

Comment: Link is broken (at least for me)

Comment: @FredrikLundin please check now

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12522478/2521893

Comment: @FredrikLundin that issue was that he was not able to connect the device to server, but I am able to connect I am only getting the issue on some devices

Comment: I see. Could it be related to permission on those specific devices?

Comment: Which permission @FredrikLundin. the app currently has a camera, location, SMS, storage and telephone permissions

Comment: I'm really not sure, as I've never worked with this. But since the error is indicating something about connecting to a host, then maybe internet/wifi permissions of some kind maybe?