# EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host) with Microsoft Azure and JTDS

Tags: android, android-studio, networking, jdbc, azure-sql-database

I am working on an android app which is associated with azure database
however when i test the app on my home netowrk , the application runs without any errors
when i go out or connect to another wifi network
this error occur

```
W/System.err: java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: failed to connect to devserverall.database.windows.net/xx.xxx.xxx.xx (port 1433) from /yyy.yyy.y.yyy (port 48262) after 30000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:436)
W/System.err:     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:236)
        at com.example.helpy.BackgroundTask2.connection(BackgroundTask2.java:32)
        at com.example.helpy.BackgroundTask2.executelist(BackgroundTask2.java:47)
        at com.example.helpy.BackgroundTask2.doInBackground(BackgroundTask2.java:113)
        at com.example.helpy.BackgroundTask2.doInBackground(BackgroundTask2.java:16)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

i use jtds module to connect to azure with this connection string

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://devserverall.database.windows.net:1433;DatabaseName=xxx;user=xxxx@devserverall;password=xxxxx;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, it looks like a network connectivity problem, you could verify if:

- The application has a successful connection to the Internet from the wifi network. Make sure that the WiFi or cell is turned on and operational.
- The application outgoing public IP address has changed from your wifi network, you could add the new client IP to your Azure SQL server firewall, refer to [this](https://msftplayground.com/2017/01/adding-your-client-ip-to-the-azure-sql-server-firewall/).
- The port 1433 is blocked in your wifi network.

For more details, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522396/tcp-ip-client-ehostunreach-no-route-to-host/12522478).